Why this simple node-notifier code doesn't work?
The question is explicited in the title: why this code doesn't throw a system notification? I'm currently working on windows 11 and even with Growl it doesn't work. No notification is displayed at all. Obviously no error or exception is raised and I've tried multiple times to reinstall node-notifier. To assure you I'm installing it properly, if I uninstall it, it gives me the standard error "Can't find a module named..."
import nn from 'node-notifier'

let windowsToasterNotifier = new nn.WindowsToaster({
    withFallback: true
});

windowsToasterNotifier.notify({
    title: "Windows Toaster Notification",
    message: "This is a notification sent from the Windows Toaster Notifier",
    sound: true,
})

